# Build Interrupt when performing Duplicator backup in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache

I'm doing some web work for a client, and I want to experiment with their wordpress site on my local server. In order to do this, I'm trying to use the Duplicator plugin so I can just download the backupfiles and deploy them on my localhost.

The projected file size for my backup is well over the recommended (840MB, or 450MB if I exclude a bunch of files I'd rather have), so I've created a php5.ini and made the following settings

```
max_execution_time=900
mysql.connect_timeout = 900
```

These are properly reflected when I do a phpinfo()

I still get the same error over and over, so I checked the server error logs, and I see the following:

```
mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 120 seconds, referer http://mysite/wp-admin/admin.php?page=duplicator&tab=new3
End of script output before headers: admin-ajax.php, referer http://mysite/wp-admin/admin.php?page=duplicator&tab=new3
```

Is there another setting I need to make somewhere? This is all happening on a godaddy shared hosting account, so I'm hoping it isn't anything I can't access.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with the free version of Duplicator. However, I decided to go for the Pro version without knowing if it would fix the problem. It did. Not just by installing it but more in the way it presented solutions for me while running it.. Quite extraordinary actually. :) It sort of figured out that at first I got stuck at 5%, then it gave me links to fix that. After that, I got stuck after repeating from (I don't remeber exactly but) 63% then back to 40%.. :/ It presented more solutions to fix that, and finally it also helped in fixing so that I changed the settings to use https for connecting to admin-ajax.php. Now it works like a charm and creates backups to my google drive once a day.